# FileWatcher typicall implementation?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I am building an app, where I will watching the files. I am pretty fresh in programming so I (maybe) have little issue, because I dont have some real practice. My program its working, but I dont know how is usally implemented in "real" software. Please overview and comment. Because I like to have much as is possible in DateFiles class and less is possible in MainViewModel.
Yes app in build on MVVM base.

My Current state:

- In my MainViewModel

  public static string ConfigurationFilesSourcePath2;

  ```
  private void InitializeFiles()
  {
      // New instance of DateFiles
      DF = new DataFiles();

      // Path to DateFiles
      DF.ConfigurationFilesSourcePath = ConfigurationFilesSourcePath;

      // Run Initialization method to establish "filewatching"
      DF.InitializeFiles();

      // Refresh ListView in View
      RefreshFileList();

      // Assign a Handler to PropertyChanged event
      DF.PropertyChanged += DF_PropertyChanged;
  }

  // If something change inside DateFiles
  private void DF_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      RefreshFileList();
  }

  // Refresh file list
  public void RefreshFileList()
  {
      fileslist = new ObservableCollection<Files>();

      foreach (var item in DF.fileslist)
      {
          fileslist.Add(item);
      }

      NotifyPropertyChanged("fileslist");
  }
  ```
- DataFiles class:

  ```
   public class DataFiles : ViewModelBase
   {
  public FileSystemWatcher filewatcher;
  public string ConfigurationFilesSourcePath;
  public ObservableCollection<Files> fileslist { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Files>();

  public void InitializeFiles()
  {
      // Create a new FileSystemWatcher
      filewatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

      // Set filter to only catch XAL files
      filewatcher.Filter = "*.txt";

      // Set the path
      filewatcher.Path = ConfigurationFilesSourcePath;

      // Subscribe to the Created event
      filewatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
      filewatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
      filewatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
      filewatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileOnRenamed);

      // Enable the FileSystemWatcher events
      filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

      RefreshFilesList();
  }

  private void FileOnchanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
  {
      RefreshFilesList();
  }

  private void FileOnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
  {
      RefreshFilesList();
  }

  public void RefreshFilesList()
  {
      fileslist.Clear();

      DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationFilesSourcePath);

      string[] extensions = new[] { ".txt" };

      int nof = 0;
      foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray())
      {
          nof++;

          fileslist.Add(new Files()
          {
              FileId = nof,
              FileName = file.Name,
              FileChanged = file.LastWriteTime.ToString(),
              FileCreated = file.CreationTime.ToString(),
              OnlyNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)
          });
          NotifyPropertyChanged("fileslist");
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code. Among most important ones - you rebuild whole file list on every change (while FileSystemEventArgs arguments provide you with info about what has really changed and where) and you don't update your ObservableCollection on UI thread. Look at the following code (but keep in mind that is just a sample for you to spot some problems):

```
public class DataFiles : IDisposable {
    public FileSystemWatcher filewatcher;
    private readonly object fileListLock = new object();
    // you don't need public setter on this
    public ObservableCollection<Files> Fileslist { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Files>();

    // pass path here, no need to use property
    public void InitializeFiles(string path) {
        // dispose existing watcher, if any
        DisposeWatcher();
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher
        filewatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        // Set filter to only catch XAL files
        filewatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        // Set the path
        filewatcher.Path = path;
        // Subscribe to the Created event
        filewatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileOnchanged);
        filewatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileOnRenamed);
        // don't RefreshFilesList on UI thread, that might take some time and will block UI
        Task.Run(() => RefreshFilesList());
        // Enable the FileSystemWatcher events
        filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void FileOnchanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        // lock here to avoid race conditions with RefreshFilesList
        lock (fileListLock) {
            // better use dictionary to avoid looping over all files
            // but looping is still much better than rebuilding whole list
            var file = Fileslist.FirstOrDefault(c => String.Equals(c.FullPath, e.FullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (file != null) {
                if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
                    ; // delete
                else
                    ; // update file properties
            }
            else {
                // add new, unless event is delete
            }
        }
    }

    private void FileOnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e) {
        lock (fileListLock) {
            // better use dictionary to avoid looping over all files
            var file = Fileslist.FirstOrDefault(c => String.Equals(c.FullPath, e.OldFullPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (file != null) {
                file.FullPath = e.FullPath;
            }
            else {
                // add new
            }
        }
    }

    public void RefreshFilesList() {
        // you need to lock here, because there is a race condition between this method and FileOnRenamed \ FileOnChanged, 
        // and you might lose some updates or get duplicates. 
        lock (fileListLock) {
            // update ObservableCollection on UI thread
            OnUIThreadDo(() => {
                Fileslist.Clear();
            });

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filewatcher.Path);
            int nof = 0;

            var files = new List<Files>();
            // just use EnumerateFiles
            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt")) {
                nof++;
                int tmp = nof;
                // if you are working with UI (that is most likely the case if you use ObservableCollection) -
                // you need to update that collection from UI thread if you have bound controls                    
                files.Add(new Files() {
                    FileId = tmp,
                    FullPath = file.FullName,
                    FileChanged = file.LastWriteTime,
                    FileCreated = file.CreationTime,
                });
                // don't do that
                // NotifyPropertyChanged("fileslist");
            }

            // publish them all to collection on UI thread
            OnUIThreadDo(() => {
                foreach (var file in files)
                    Fileslist.Add(file);
            });
        }
    }

    private void OnUIThreadDo(Action a) {
        if (Application.Current.CheckAccess())
            a();
        else
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(a);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        DisposeWatcher();
    }

    private void DisposeWatcher() {
        if (filewatcher != null) {
            filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            filewatcher.Created -= FileOnchanged;
            filewatcher.Deleted -= FileOnchanged;
            filewatcher.Changed -= FileOnchanged;
            filewatcher.Renamed -= FileOnRenamed;
            filewatcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

public class Files : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ // implement INotifyPropertyChanged, because you need to reflect property changes in UI
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string FullPath { get; set; }
    public string FileName => Path.GetFileName(FullPath);
    public DateTime FileChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime FileCreated { get; set; }
    public string OnlyNameWithoutExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullPath);
}
```